# CountIfs formula error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below countIFs formula to get the count only when col I has "Duplicate TT" and col K has "Tablet" and "NA".

But i'm not getting the correct count. What is the mistake here?

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")
[AH123] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Duplicate TT") + wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), "Tablet", .Range("K:K"), "NA")
End With
```

Comment: Post  sample of your sheet. Col K can't be Tablet AND NA at the same time.
If you want Col K to be Tablet OR NA thats a different condition. 
To be clear you want t count
IF COL I = DuplicateTT AND (col K is Tablet Or NA)?
Post a sample input and output and we can help better

Comment: Yes correct..Col K should either be Tablet or NA

Comment: Col I is independent of col K?

Comment: Yes, Col I should have "Duplicate TT" and K should either have Tablet or NA

Comment: You need to be more precise.
COL I Duplicate TT must exist when Col K is Tablet?
In otherwords cok I must be Duplicate TT and Col K can be either Tablet or NA?

Comment: to be more simple..in terms of excel filtering, I have applied filters for all columns, selecting only "Duplicate TT" from Col I and selecting "Tablet" and "NA" from col K filter..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the formula you want

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS("I:I", "Duplicate TT", K:K, "Tablet"), COUNTIFS("I:I", "Duplicate TT", K:K, "NA"))
```

in vba

```
[AH123] =  WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), "Duplicate TT", Range("K:K"), "Tablet") + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), "Duplicate TT", Range("K:K"), "NA") )
```

Comment: I think the PO wants it in VBA

Comment: Yes I want it in VBA

Comment: The VBA code gives the Output as 0 @dgorti...pasting my comment from above if you have missed it "to be more simple..in terms of excel filtering, I have applied filters for all columns, selecting only "Duplicate TT" from Col I and selecting "Tablet" and "NA" from col K filter."